# Push rejected, failed to compile Python app, pythonnet: finished with status 'error'

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Python based webapp to Heroku but I am getting this error:

```
error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
```

I tried updating `setuptools` and `wheel` but its still happening.

Here is the full error message:

```
Running setup.py install for pythonnet: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for pythonnet: finished  with status 'error'
remote:            Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6ls167h_/pythonnet/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hdv3d_au-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
remote:            usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
remote:               or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
remote:               or: -c --help-commands
remote:               or: -c cmd --help
remote:
remote:            error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
```

Here is my `requirements.txt`:

```
altgraph==0.16.1
astroid==2.2.5
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.1.0
autopep8==1.4.4
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
chicken==0.1.0
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.1
Django==2.2.1
dominate==2.3.5
egg==0.2.0
entrypoints==0.3
eyeD3==0.8.10
flake8==3.7.7
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-Bootstrap4==4.0.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
future==0.17.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==0.18
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
lxml==4.3.4
macholib==1.11
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
more-itertools==7.0.0
packaging==19.0
pefile==2019.4.18
pluggy==0.12.0
py==1.8.0
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pyflakes==2.1.1
PyInstaller==3.4
pylint==2.3.1
pymessenger==0.0.7.0
pyparsing==2.4.0
pytest==4.6.3
python-magic==0.4.15
pythonnet==2.4.0
pytube==9.5.1
pytz==2019.1
pywebview==2.4
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
requests==2.22.0
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==1.9.2
spotify-downloader==0.4.2
spotipy==2.4.4
sqlparse==0.3.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
urllib3==1.25.3
virtualenv==16.6.0
visitor==0.1.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
Werkzeug==0.15.4
wrapt==1.11.2
WTForms==2.2.1
zipp==0.5.1
```

And here is my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Comment: This is a strange error to see on Heroku. Are you using any very old libraries? Please [edit] your question and include your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`.

Comment: okay , i will include the requirements.txt

Comment: @Chris what about now ?

Comment: Oh, wait. `pythonnet` is for running Python with .NET? At minimum this will significantly complicate deployment. What are you using .NET for?

Comment: @Chris sorry, idk what you are talking about, are you reffering to the microsoft framework ?

Comment: @Chris if it helps i got the requirements.txt from doing : pip freeze > requirements.txt

Comment: Yes, the Microsoft framework. You have [`pythonnet==2.4.0`](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/) ("a package that gives Python programmers… integration with the .NET…"), as well as some Windows-specific things like `pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0` that definitely won't work on Heroku (it doesn't run Windows), in your `requirements.txt`. "if it helps i got the requirements.txt from doing : pip freeze > requirements.txt"—are you using a virtual environment? I suspect you've got a whole bunch of stuff installed into one environment (likely your system-level one) that you don't need for this application.

Comment: @then what are the things i should get rid of ?

Comment: Edit : i made a new directory and tried again without pythonnet or pywin32 and it worked thanx man

Comment: You should get rid of everything you don't need. I strongly recommend reading up on virtual environments and starting to use them.

Comment: thanx man thr problem  was fixed but now i am facing a new problem :    at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's a good idea to use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to isolate one application's dependencies from others. Based on the contents of your `requirements.txt` I suspect that you're not doing this.

`pywin32` definitely won't work on Heroku since it doesn't run Windows. `pythonnet` might be usable on Heroku but would require at least a custom buildpack since [Heroku doesn't officially support .NET](https://help.heroku.com/PAT3YEDU/does-heroku-support-net-applications). If you don't really need them for this application, remove them from your `requirements.txt` and deploy again.

Ideally you would also remove any other libraries that you don't actually need, but as long as they run on Heroku they shouldn't cause deploy errors.